# Having an issue with CSV file not creating

Tags: python, csv

```
chars = list(range(0,10)) 
numbers_list = list(range(0,25))
for comb in itertools.combinations_with_replacement(chars, 5): 
        for A in numbers_list:
            pure = str(A) + ':' + str(comb) 
            B = pure.replace(")", "").replace("(", "").replace("'", "").replace(",", "").replace(" ", "") 
            C = hashlib.sha256(B.encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()
            rows = [A , str(B), str(C)]
            print(rows)

header = ['A', 'B', 'C'] 
with open('data.csv', 'w', encoding='UTF8', newline='') as f: 
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(header)
    writer.writerow(rows) 

print('end')
```

Good afternoon everyone,
I am having an issue with csv file not being created. The rows are printing out in IDE, but when the script is done running all the rows of combinations after a few hours, it does not create the CSV file with the rows. I am bit new to programing in python. I would be really appreciative  the help! Thank you!

Comment: Each time through the `for A in numbers_list` loop, you reassign `rows` to a fresh value, which throws away the previous value.  So `rows` ends up with only the last value from that loop.  But even so, the csv file should still have been created with that one row.  If you don't see the csv file at all, you must be looking in the wrong directory.

Comment: The csv file will be created in the _current directory_, which is not necessarily the same directory as the python program file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest a much more simple approach. Did you ever considered to use the pandas module for this kind of job? Pandas module will let you save much more easier to csv, xls... Give it a try.

```
import itertools
import hashlib
import pandas as pd

chars = list(range(0,10))
numbers_list = list(range(0,25))

rows = []
for combination in itertools.combinations_with_replacement(chars, 5):
        for number in numbers_list:
            pure_number_a = str(number) + ':' + str(combination) 
            pure_number_b = pure_number_a.replace(")", "").replace("(", "").replace("'", "").replace(",", "").replace(" ", "") 
            pure_number_c = hashlib.sha256(pure_number_b.encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()

            rows.append([pure_number_a , pure_number_b, pure_number_c])


df = pd.DataFrame(data=rows, columns=['A', 'B', 'C'])
df.to_csv('data.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I have not used Pandas yet but ill give it a try.

Comment: @JuanSotoValdez I am sure you'll love it!

Comment: @JuanSotoValdez on another look at the code, I think you should consider using ```strip()``` instead of the replace sequences, as it follows:
```pure_number_b = pure_number_a.strip("(,)' ")```

Comment: I want to up vote your help. But it tells me "You need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote". My apologies, I am new to stackoverflow. But I really appreciative your help!!

Comment: @JuanSotoValdez, you can still accept this solution by clicking the checkmark at the top of the answer.

Comment: @JuanSotoValdez with great pleasure. Actually I am new to stackoverflow, also trying to learn and improve my Python skills as much as I can. This was my first post here, so thanks for the appreciation! :) Good luck with your learning experience!

Answer (score 1):

[John Gordon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/494134/john-gordon) is correct, you need to retain each row in a list, then loop through that list when writing each row to the csv file

this script works for me

```py
import itertools, hashlib, csv

data = []
chars = list(range(0,10)) 
numbers_list = list(range(0,25))
for comb in itertools.combinations_with_replacement(chars, 5): 
    for A in numbers_list:
        pure = str(A) + ':' + str(comb) 
        B = pure.replace(")", "").replace("(", "").replace("'", "").replace(",", "").replace(" ", "") 
        C = hashlib.sha256(B.encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()
        rows = [A , str(B), str(C)]
        data.append(rows)

            

header = ['A', 'B', 'C'] 
with open('data.csv', 'w', encoding='UTF8', newline='') as f: 
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(header)
    for row in data:
        writer.writerow(row) 

print('end')
```